# When deploy on Heroku, report TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Tags: python, django, heroku

I disable `collectstatic` with command

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

After successfully push my project to Heroku, manually `collectstatic` as below:

```
$ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic
```

Unfortunately, Heroku report errors referring to `manage.py`

```
Running python manage.py collectstatic on ⬢ fierce-cove-94300... up, run.6296 (Free)
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 173, in handle
    if self.is_local_storage() and self.storage.location:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 239, in inner
    return func(self._wrapped, *args)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 283, in location
    return abspathu(self.base_location)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 371, in abspath
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
```

**settings.py**

```
#Heroku Setting
cwd = os.getcwd()
if cwd == "/app" or cwd[:4] == "/tmp":
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = { #DATABASES plurual
        "default": dj_database_url.config(default="postgres://localhost"),
    }

    #Honor the "X-Forwarded-Proto" header for request.is_secure().
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", 'https')

    # Allow all host headers
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

    #Static asset configuration
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = (BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

How to solve such a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in your `STATIC_ROOT` setting. As the error message states, you are passing a tuple instead of a path:

```
STATIC_ROOT = (BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

change it to:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```